# Thymeleaf ошибка

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

В чем ошибка? хочу чтобы получился

```
<option disabled value="XS">XS</option>
```

если el.isXS() == false

Мой код:

```
 <option th:attr="${el.isXS() ? '' : 'disabled'}" value="XS">XS</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymleaf [th:attr](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes) подразумевает что вы укажете имя атрибута (`"attribute_name=attribute_value"`) ...

```
<option th:attr="value=${el.isXS() ? '' : 'XS'}">XS</option>
```

Для станндартных boolean атриутов Thymeleaf предлагает целый набор [фиксированных атрибутов](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes) (один из них `th:disabled`) ...

```
<option th:disabled="${el.isXS}" value="XS">XS</option>
```